# SFINAE User-Defined-Conversion Operator

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, if-constexpr

I'm trying to do a templated user-defined-conversion that uses design by introspection.

In C++20 I can do the following:

```
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
        if constexpr( requires { PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this); } )
        {
            return PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this);
        }
        else
        {
            T x;
            std::memcpy(&x, &data, sizeof(x));
            return x;
        }
    }
```

i.e. if `PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(const struct PFCursor&)` is defined then use it else do a memcpy. (longer example here in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/abed1vsK3)

I love this approach but unfortunately this library will need to work on C++17 too.

So I've been trying SFINAE as an alternative to the concepts but it's very tricky.
I finally managed to get something similar but with a templated method `as` rather than the user-defined-conversion operator itself:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_from_cursor : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_from_cursor<T, decltype( PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(std::declval<struct PFCursor>()), void() ) > : std::true_type { };

// ...

    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<has_from_cursor<T>::value, T> as() const
    {
        return PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this);
    }

    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<!has_from_cursor<T>::value, T> as() const
    {
        T x;
        std::memcpy(&x, &data, sizeof(x));
        return x;
    }
```

I tried the following which compiles but does not work (I can't cast with it):

```
    template<typename T>
    operator std::enable_if_t<has_from_cursor<T>::value, T>() const
    {
        return PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this);
    }

    template<typename T>
    operator std::enable_if_t<!has_from_cursor<T>::value, T>() const
    {
        T x;
        std::memcpy(&x, &data, sizeof(x));
        return x;
    }
```

Longer example here: https://godbolt.org/z/5r9Mbo18h

So two questions:

- Can I do effectively what I can do with concepts with just SFINAE in C++17 for the user defined conversion operator?
- Is there a simpler way to do the `as` approach than the type traits & `enable_if`? Ideally I'd like to do something like define the default templated method and then have a specialisation to be preferred if the condition is there (i.e. there is a meta class with a static member function defined).

Thanks!

Comment: I've just realised I can conveniently call the `as` method from `operator T()` and the problem goes away.. but still if anyone has a cleaner approach to this I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do effectively what I can do with concepts with just SFINAE in C++17 for the user defined conversion operator?

Consider that C++17 support `if constepr`. Given that you've developed a `has_from_cursor` custom type traits that inherit from `std::true_type` or from `std::false_type`, you can use it for `if constexp`.

I mean (caution: code not tested)

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const
{ // .............VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    if constexpr( has_from_cursos<T>::value )
    {
        return PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this);
    }
    else
    {
        T x;
        std::memcpy(&x, &data, sizeof(x));
        return x;
    }
}
```

> Is there a simpler way to do the as approach than the type traits & enable_if? Ideally I'd like to do something like define the default templated method and then have a specialisation to be preferred if the condition is there (i.e. there is a meta class with a static member function defined).

I suppose you can try tag-dispatching...

I mean something as calling 'as()', from `operator T()` with an additional `int` argument

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const
{ return as<T>(0); } // <-- call as() with a int
```

where there is a `as()` specific for `from_cursos` class enabled, that receive an unused `int` and is simply SFINAE enabled/disabled through `decltype()`

```
template <typename T>  // ........accept an int; best match
decltype(PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this)) as (int) const
 { return PFMeta<T>::from_cursor(*this); }
```

and a generic `as()`, receiving a `long`

```
template <typename T>
T as (long) const // <-- accept a long; worst match
 {
   T x;
   std::memcpy(&x, &data, sizeof(x));
   return x;
 }
```

The trick is the unused argument: a `int`.

When the specialized `as()` is enabled, if preferred because accept a `int` so is a better match.

When the specialized `as()` is disabled, remain the generic `as()` as better-than-nothig match.